# Combo box key up event in C#.net

Tags: c#

I have taken combo box on C# windows application and key up event on combo box  but after entering number or text in combo box, cursor automatically moves to the front. How can i solve this problem. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: show us at least your `comboBox1_KeyUp(...` method?

Comment: Please share some code around the problem.